# (Unable to) Get started with the Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

My goal is to use the FB login button so that FB users can log into my ASP.NET MVC 3 website. It seems that things have changed recently with the Facebook C# SDK and all the [old examples](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation) will not work with the new version. I've tried for a day to get them to work... I'm working off of the tutorial [Getting Started with the Facebook C# SDK for ASP.NET](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started)

Currently when I browse to `http://localhost:8033/` it seems to automatically log me in (even after a fresh restart of Chrome) because it shows "*my-name* uses *my-app-name*" and shows my picture. I expected it to instead show a FB login button. And when I go to `http://localhost:8033/Home/About` I get an error that `Session["AccessToken"]` is null (which makes sense because it's clearly not getting set).

Here's what I have:

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Facebook;

namespace FacebookTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
            var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
            string name = result.name;
            string id = result.id;

            ViewBag.Message = "Hello id: " + id;

            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult FacebookLogin(HttpContext context)
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request["accessToken"];
            context.Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

            return RedirectToAction("About");
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            //appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
            appId: '<MY-NUMBER-REMOVED>', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // TODO: Handle the access token
                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                //form.setAttribute("action", '/FacebookLogin.ashx');
                form.setAttribute("action", '/Home/FacebookLogin');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

**About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     @ViewBag.Message
</p>
```

Can you tell me how to fix this so that a FB login button is displayed, and when clicked it asks the users to do a FB authentication, sends them back, and then my app recognizes them as a logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As for the Login button**, if you are logged in to Facebook prior to visiting your app you will see the faces instead of the login button, the only way to get the Login button back is to go to facebook.com and do a logout or possibly do a facebook logout using the C# SDK. Depending on your requirements this may or may not be what you wanted. There is a bit about [Re-Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/) in the SDK documentation if that is what you really want.

I've tweaked your app by removing the submit() and replaced it with an ajax post, The FacebookLogin action was changed and I added some error handling on the About action. Your original app will work but it will automatically redirect to About if you are logged in to Facebook.

**Update** Added a login link which does not use Javascript, insert appid and appsecret and adjust portnumber accordingly. This was adapted from the server side login sample found [here](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample) which is far prettier than this code :)

**Note** The state value being passed in the server side flow should be a unqiue value that you should validate in the ConnectResponse() method, i.e. generate a value in FacebookLoginNoJs and make sure it's  the same in ConnectResponse to prevent cross site request [forgery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Facebook;

namespace FacebookTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Please log in first";

            if (Session["AccessToken"] != null)
            {
                var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
                var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                try
                {
                    dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
                    string name = result.name;
                    string id = result.id;

                    ViewBag.Message = "Hello id: " + id + " aka " + name;
                }
                catch (FacebookOAuthException x)
                {

                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        public void FacebookLogin(string uid, string accessToken)
        {
            var context = this.HttpContext;
            context.Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;
        }

        public ActionResult FacebookLoginNoJs()
        {
            return Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY-APPID-REMOVED&redirect_uri=http://localhost:45400/Home/ConnectResponse&state=secret");
        }

        public ActionResult ConnectResponse(string state, string code, string error, string error_reason, string error_description, string access_token, string expires)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = new FacebookClient();
                    dynamic result = client.Post("oauth/access_token",
                                              new
                                              {
                                                  client_id = "MY-APPID-REMOVED",
                                                  client_secret = "MY-APP-SECRET-REMOVED",
                                                  redirect_uri = "http://localhost:45400/Home/ConnectResponse",
                                                  code = code
                                              });

                    Session["AccessToken"] = result.access_token;

                    if (result.ContainsKey("expires"))
                        Session["ExpiresIn"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(result.expires);

                }
                catch
                {
                    // handle errors
                }
            }
            else
            {
               // Declined, check error
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            //appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
            appId: 'MY-APPID-REMOVED', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {

                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                var url = '/Home/FacebookLogin';
                $.post(url, { uid: uid, accessToken: accessToken }, function (data) {
                });

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1"></div>

@Html.ActionLink("The NoJs Login", "FacebookLoginNoJs", "Home")
```

**About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
        @ViewBag.Message
</p>
```

Comment: Removed step 1-3 as this no longer is true, must have been fixed :). Added a link that triggers a server side login flow.