# The type or namespace name 'FaceBookClient' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, facebook, .net-assembly

None of the other questions regarding this question were able to answer this. I am new to programming, and I am just trying to add a FacebookLogin option to the website.
I built all the Javascript they wanted, and there is no error there(I don't think). In the interest of saving time, and that I am working on multiple computers. I am going to post pictures of all the code. I have added excess using statements to try and get the reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6MOT.jpg

If you need anymore information let me know. And I will edit this page.

Comment: posting pictures of code isn't as useful when you want people to try to help you find compile errors... I'm not seeing any references to namespaces that i would expect to see from an external resource (which i'm assuming the facebook API is)  Do you have the correct project references set up?

Comment: @Kritner I had the incorrect sdk, and added the using statement. I am now receiving this error when running in google chrome http://www.imgur.com/gn9sehl

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you just have some simple issues to fix in your IDE/project. The below instructions are for Visual Studio, but can be slightly altered for other IDEs.

First, *make sure you have a reference to the Facebook SDK for .NET* (I'm assuming you're using **[Outercurve's library](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/)** from the looks of it):

- In Visual Studio, check in the Solution Explorer window, then expand the "References", and make sure you see it there.
- If it's not there, right-click "References", then "Manage Nuget Packages". When the Packages screen pops up, ensure in the left-pane that you have "Online -> nuget.org" selected. In the top right of the Packages window, in the "Search Online" textbox, enter:
  **`facebook sdk`** and press "enter". On my screen, it's the second search result. To ensure you have the correct one, ensure that the "Created by" field says "Outercurve Foundation" before you accept it. Once you know you have the right package, hit the "Install" button, and it will be added to your project.

Once you have verified you have the correct reference, if you are still having the issue, *make sure you have a "using" statement in your class file, to ensure library types you are using are recognized*. In this example, I believe that would be:

```
using Facebook;
```

From the images of code you provided, I didn't see that statement in there, so that may be the problem, if this is fact the library you are referencing.

Comment: Great! No build errors. Now I assume something is wrong in my routes? This is the new Error when I run in Google Chrome. http://www.imgur.com/gn9sehI

Comment: I have posted an image of the new error in above comment, I added the using Facebook statement, and installed the correct sdk.

Comment: Ok, so you are getting a 404 on what looks like an HTTP handler called ~/FacebookLogin.ashx. From your code though, you are working with ASP.Net MVC (not ASP.Net). I suspect you need to re-structure things a bit. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434208/unable-to-get-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk) and notice how the "...ASHX" line is commented out, and the author has made an MVC version of the functionality. Whatever way you go, you will still need to write the code that gets called when the "Facebook Login" resource is hit, such as that in the SDK doc cited.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this type of application but what I found that is:

Use `Facebook.FacebookClient` instead of `FacebookClient`.